# My switch statement is not returning anything?

Tags: java, android

Im selecting a "Left" from alert dialog and after putting it into convertStatusToCode function should retrun "4" but its not?

```java
final String[] status = {"Left"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setTitle("Pick a Status");
builder.setItems(status, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        BookingStatus = convertStatusToCode(status[which]);
```

HERE IS  MY convertStatusToCode FUNCTION but it is not retruning "4" which it should return.

```java
private String convertStatusToCode(String status) {

    switch (status) {
        case "Processing":
            i = "0";
            break;
        case "Room is Allotted":
            i = "1";
            break;
        case "Sorry All Rooms Are Full":
            i = "2";
            break;
        case "Living":
            i = "3";
            break;
        case "Left":
            i = "4";
            break;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: When you set a breakpoint in the line `switch(status)` and inspect the value of `status` (variable) what value does it have at runtime?

Comment: "Left" in run time

Comment: ANd if you put a breakpoint in the line that says `return i`, what value does `i` have? also what is BookinStatus? if it's a variable (which I assume it is), don't start it with uppercase please. ` BookingStatus = convertStatusToCode(status[which]);`

Comment: i="" it gives me empty string but i don't know why

Comment: Ok, can you post your entire method, not just the switch?

Comment: Next time post all the code that is involved, not just the part *you* think is causing the problem.

Comment: Word usage: a *method* may *return* something. A `switch` statement cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should look something like this

```
  String getStatusCode(String status) {
        switch (status) {
            case "Processing":
                return "0";
            case "Room is Allotted":
                return "1";
            case "Sorry All Rooms Are Full":
                return "2";
            case "Living":
                return "3";
            case "Left":
                return "4";
            default:
                return "default_value";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You based your entire answer in the fact that the OP did not show if there was a `i` String variable declared in scope. If there wasn't, the OP would have had a compilation error. If there is, then your code does exactly the same.

Comment: shouldn't we put break after every statement?

Comment: Not if you `return`, break will only break out of the switch statement, return will do the same.

Comment: @ChiragGupta see updated answer. If I did understand correct what you need, this method should work

Answer (score 0):

Based upon what you've added in the comments, your Switch statement (albeit incomplete) shouldn't be the cause of your problem as the other posters are assuming.

You may have a problem with the completness of your `switch` cases, but that shouldn't stop the switch to work as intended.

You're saying that you DEBUG this and that `i` has the value of `""` which I cannot understand unless you are not having a return value in scope.

The answer posted by Antonis Radz is how I would write that switch if I had to.

If you write your Convert function to return like so, then you don't need the extra `i` variable, which we don't know where you declared.

If you debug this line of code (like you said you did)

`switch(value)` and you're telling us that `value` == `"Left"` then the switch is receiving the correct value at runtime.

Now your "Case" is executed (when you set a breakpoint in `case "Left"`. So the switch is, again, performing its function so far.

Then I assume you added another breakpoint in the following line(s):

```
            i = "4";
            break;
```

to see what is going on.

The first breakpoint would hit in the assignment `i=`... and so the variable `i` which I assume is declared somewhere in scope as `String i` (At the very least), is either null or contains an old value. Doesn't matter because the next breakpoint (in the `break` line) would be reached after `i` is assigned the value of the String `"4"`. So if you add a watch to `i` and inspect it right there, it must have the value of "4".

Then you return this `i` so, again, it should still be "4".

If you did all this, you would have been able to tell much closer where the variable is not being assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.

```
    public String getstatuscode(String status){
        String i="";
        switch (status) {
            case "Processing":
                i = "0";
                break;
            case "Room is Allotted":
                i = "1";
                break;
            case "Sorry All Rooms Are Full":
                i = "2";
                break;
            case "Living":
                i = "3";
                break;
            case "Left":
                i = "4";
                break;
            default:
                i = "-1";

        }
        return i;
    }
```

Declare i as String or int as your requirement. Method is same.Don't forget to remove quotes if you want to assign i as int.

Answer (score 0):

Another thought to use enum rather than switch-case here which gives more flexibility & reusability.

```
public enum BookingStatus
{

    PROCESSING("Processing", 1),
    ALLOTED_ROOM("Room is Allotted", 2),
    ALL_FULL("Sorry All Rooms Are Full", 3),
    LIVING("Living", 4),
    LEFT("LEFT", 5);

    private String status;
    private int code;

    BookingStatus(String status, int code)
    {
        this.status = status;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public static BookingStatus getCodeFromStatus(String status)
    {
        for (BookingStatus e : values()) {
            if (e.status.equals(status)) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.printf("Code for this status is %s", BookingStatus.getCodeFromStatus("Sorry All Rooms Are Full").code);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
switch (status) {
        case "Processing":
            i = "0";
            break;
        case "Room is Allotted":
            i = "1";
            break;
        case "Sorry All Rooms Are Full":
            i = "2";
            break;
        case "Living":
            i = "3";
            break;
        case "Left":
            i = "4";
          // return "4";
            break;
    }
    return i;
}
```

use `return "4";` you don't print anything in switch cases so switch can't return anything if you want to print in switch cases output then use the print method or return in any programming language.